# How to change the font size in Delphi 11 IDE?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-11-alexandria

My English is not very good, a photo will be more efficient.

I cannot find or manage the "complementary" Windows font on Delphi 11.

[image]

Comment: In the registry, in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\22.0\Theme there's a DWORD value called FontSize (or add it, if it is not there already), which applies to various parts of the IDE, which I think may include the Messages window

Comment: Thank it's work. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

This question seems solved:

In the registry, in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\22.0\Theme there's a DWORD value called FontSize (or add it, if it is not there already), which applies to various parts of the IDE, which I think may include the Messages window –
Dave Nottage
Oct 19, 2021 at 19:20

Thank it's work. Best regards –
Nicolas Marchand
Oct 20, 2021 at 5:37

So let us close it.